# number of different arrangements of $n$ squares

Tags: contest-math, problem-solving, integer-partitions

How to find the number of different arrangements of n squares with conditions that firstly every arrangement should be connected and secondly if two squares intersect they should intersect on a whole edge(not part of edge or a vertex)?
For example in the image below two arrangement on the left are allowed and the two on the right are not.

[image]

and for n=4 there are five different arrangements as shown below.

[image]

**How one should study this problem in an abstract mathematical way? Is there some kind of a partition of a number to be related to this?**

**edit 1:** symmetries (rotations and reflections) are not allowed.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring a lot of symmetrical possibilities... you are treating rotations and reflections as "the same"?  Else there should have been 19 possibilities for $n=4$ (*7 if only treating rotations as same but reflections can give different*).

Comment: yes. I will edit it

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000105 and related https://oeis.org/A000104 if you disallow "holes" in your arrangements.

Comment: These are called polyominoes.  Your $n=4$ examples are the pieces used in the game Tetris.